# How to get contents of page stylesheets using php dom?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, dom

I am new to php, can anyone suggest how to get contents of stylesheets of a page in order they appear on the page using [php dom](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ?

Let's say in head of page is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/invalid.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/blue.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

How to get contents of these stylesheets?

**Update:**

```
$url = 'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60792/replace-image-attributes-for-lazyload-plugin-data-src';
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
/* Search for <link rel=stylesheet> */
$result = $xml->xpath('link[@rel="stylesheet"]');

foreach($result as $node) { 
    echo $node->{'@attributes'}->href . "\n";
}
exit;
```

Comment: @k102: not an answer to my question. Anyways i want to combine and compress them into one. I know there are solutions but I am working on a custom library so i need to to do it for that.

Comment: Thanks, Cap, that's not an answer, but a comment :) I've thought there's another way to to your task...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it posibble to use simplexml insted of dom?

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

```
<?php

$url = 'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60792/replace-image-attributes-for-lazyload-plugin-data-src';
$url_parts = parse_url($url);

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
// A corrupt HTML string
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

/* Search for <link rel=stylesheet> */
$result = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="stylesheet"]');

foreach($result as $node) { 
    $link = $node->attributes()->href;

    if (substr($link, 0, 4) == 'http') {
        // nothing to do
    } else if (substr($link, 0, 1) == '/') {
        $link = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $link;
    } else {
        $link = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . dirname($url_parts['scheme']) . '/' . $link;
    }

    echo '--> ' . $link . "\n";
}
exit;
```

Comment: `arning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 41: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'`

Comment: `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &quot;:true,&quot;enableUserHovercards&quot;:true,&quot;site&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;WordPress&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;Q&amp;A`

Comment: `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^` and more

Comment: it seams to be invalid html, a changed my answer and nowit should work